# Way to keep the react leaflet tooltip open only when mouse is over tooltip or marker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

I am using react leaflet tooltip for a mapbox map.
I'm having a lot of trouble trying to keep react leaflet tooltip open when the mouse is over either the marker or the tooltip itself? I want to be able to open on hover and then click on something inside the tooltip, and I want to close when the mouse leaves the marker or the tooltip.

So if the mouse is in the red then the tooltip is open, and if it is not, then the tooltip is closed.

[image]

Any pointers appreciated

I tried what was available in the api https://leafletjs.com/SlavaUkraini/reference.html#tooltip, but I think there may be more customization I don't have the expertise to build may be needed to pull off this behavior.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to not set it to close when the mouse leaves.

Then it will be up to the user to either click on the map or click "close" to close the popup.

If any other markers are hovered that show popups then the original one will be automatically closed.